# MVC unobtrusive doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've set *jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js* and *jquery.js* file and in *web.config* I've set

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

But it still refreshes the page instead of doing javascript validation.

Also my model has:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Reguired")]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Reguired")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Please help

Comment: But have you added *jquery.validate.js* and *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js*?

Comment: *jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js* is for unobtrusive ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `add jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in that order. `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is to make Ajax.* helpers work, it has nothing to do with validation.